# Find $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3} \in \mathbb C$ for which $f^{*}=a_{0}p_{0}^{*}+ a_{1}p_{1}^{*}+a_{2}p_{2}^{*}+ a_{3}p_{3}^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> In the linear space $\mathbb C[x]_{3}$ is a basis: $p_{0}(x)=1$, $p_{1}(x)=x$, $p_{2}(x)=x(x-i)$, $p_{3}(x)=x(x-i)(x-1)$.
>  $(p_{0}^{*}, p_{1}^{*}, p_{2}^{*}, p_{3}^{*})$ is a basis of space $(\mathbb C[x]_{3})^{*}$ which is dual for a basis $(p_{0}, p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3})$. 
> Functional $f^{*} \in (\mathbb C[x]_{3})^{*}$ is such that $f^{*}(p)=p(-i)$. 
> Find $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3} \in \mathbb C$ for which $f^{*}=a_{0}p_{0}^{*}+ a_{1}p_{1}^{*}+a_{2}p_{2}^{*}+ a_{3}p_{3}^{*}$.

Can you get me some tips to this question? I never had similar task and I do not even know what to look for to start this task. I'm weak from line functionalities and it's too hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the definition of the dual basis, 
$$p_j^*(p_i) = \begin{cases}0 & i \ne j\\1 & i = j\end{cases}$$

So if $$f^* = a_0p_0^* + a_1p_1^* + a_2p_2^* + a_3p_3^*$$ then
$$f^*(p_i) = a_i$$
for all $i$

And since $f^*(P) = P(-i)$ for any polynomial $P$, you can calculate $f^*(p_i)$ easily.